# Count the time the file downloading time by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, download

I've search on Google and tries to find some script about this but I can only find out file download time count (e.g. 5 people have download this file) and some concept way that pretent user have some speed and use math and count it out.

But what I want is when user click the download button which downloads a file, a timer starts and it'll stop when the file is totally downloaded.

How can this be achieve, I know I can call function to start stopwatch when the download button is click but don't know how to stop it while the download finish?

P.S. I'm currently using `window.open(file URL here);` to start downloading file

Comment: how you are start downloading ? share some code, and what type of file ? Until you specify, its too broad

Comment: @user2486 I updated the question I'm currently using window.open()

Comment: @Munucial read this [article](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)